# Get spiderable: phantomjs failed because of permission denied

Tags: meteor

I bundled my application and put it onto my server. I am running the app via upstart:

```
exec sudo -u myuser PORT=3005 MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/ms ROOT_URL=http://www.example.com/ /usr/bin/node /var/www/priv/example.com/bundle/main.js >> $
```

The important part (i think) is:

```
exec sudo -u myuser
```

When i curl my app via:

```
curl http://www.example.com/?_escaped_fragment_=
```

I get an empty body. My log file says:

```
spiderable: phantomjs failed: { [Error: Command failed: /bin/bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
Can't open '/dev/stdin'
] killed: false, code: 255, signal: null }
stderr: /bin/bash: /root/.bashrc: Permission denied
Can't open '/dev/stdin'
```

I did chmod 777 on /root/.bashrc but without any success. If i do `/bin/bash /root/.bashrc` as 'myuser' i also get permission denied.

Could any one tell me how to set the permissions so that phantomjs can do what it has to do? Can i specify that ~/.bashrc is used anywhere? I would really love to see my stuff on google :-)

Thanks alot!
Manuel

**Updates**:

I have phantom.js 1.8.2 installed via npm.
Running the application as root does not help. Error then is:

```
spiderable: phantomjs failed: { [Error: Command failed: Can't open '/dev/stdin' ] killed: false, code: 255, signal: null } stderr: Can't open '/dev/stdin'
```

I found out, that it seems to be a package that causes the problem. I opened an issu here:
[github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/issues/3](http://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/issues/3)

Comment: Update: tried to start the app as root. Log says: 

spiderable: phantomjs failed: { [Error: Command failed: Can't open '/dev/stdin'
] killed: false, code: 255, signal: null }
stderr: Can't open '/dev/stdin'

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but you should make sure the version of phantomjs on your server is the most recent version.  Versions 1.4 and below require an X window server, and the apt repository for Ubuntu still had 1.4.  Here's the phantomjs FAQ explaining this a bit: http://phantomjs.org/faq.html.

Comment: Oh, also make sure that you've installed phantomjs!  Meteor's spiderable package doesn't install it for you.  I was confused about that for quite a while.

Comment: Hey zorlak, i have phantom.js version 1.8.2 installed. I found out that the problem seems to be in a package i use. Meteor-roles. I opened an issue here: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles/issues/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alanning fixed the problem but spiderable still did not work. The solution was to remove phantomjs because i installed it via npm. I then reinstalled it from http://phantomjs.org/download.html directly. Now it is working!

Comment: On the latest version (1.9.1) this is still happening.

Comment: Latest version (1.9.2) and still happening.

Comment: Quick followup.  I did not want to abandon packaging on the server, so extracted the binary release of PhantomJS into the project’s directory, then modified the projects PATH environment variable so spiderable “sees” this version first.

Comment: Ever find out how to use it via npm? I'd love to make it through npm so we don't have to worry about using different programs to get it on different OSs (linux, mac, etc)

Comment: To update on the progress -- if you run the phantomjs command with sudo, it seems to operate the same. I'm not sure why though -- hope this helps someone (and please update this if you find out why!)

Comment: Still happening using PhantomJS 1.9.8

Answer (score -1):

I found that problem again, the problem were publications on the server-side that in some cases just returned but did not stop the subscription.

e.g. on server i have a publication with

```
return unless @userId
```

The correct way would be:

```
return this.stop() unless @userId
```

If a crawler comes, it will never be authenticated, so be careful to end publications correctly.